# Ignore keys for null values when sending a post submit via a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We currently have the following setup which works where we are sending a POST request via a form with a body and also redirects to a new endpoint.

```
// this is from another file. Just adding it here to show that myRef is a useRef hook. 
const myRef = React.useRef();

export const postData = (myRef, token, link) => {
  myRef.current.children[0].value = token;
  myRef.current.action = link;
  myRef.current.submit();
};

const MyForm = ({
  myRef,
}) => (
  <form id="MyForm" ref={myRef} method="POST">
    <!-- custom_token ends up as the key for the token value being set above as the post body -->
    <input name="custom_token" type="hidden" />
  </form>
);

export default MyForm;
```

I am trying to add more optional parameters to the post body. Since they are optional, only want to send if data exists.

But if I do the following, I still end up sending data with the `newkey` and empty value.

```
export const postData = (myRef, token, link, newValue) => {
  myRef.current.children[0].value = token;

  // NEW addition. Even though I am only setting value if it exists, 
  // the post body still ends up with newKey and empty value. 
  // I don't want to have the newKey and empty value at all since the value is not present.
  if (newValue) {
    myRef.current.children[1].value = newValue;
  }

  myRef.current.action = link;
  myRef.current.submit();
};

<form id="MyForm" ref={myRef} method="POST">
    <input name="custom_token" type="hidden" />

    <!-- NEW addition. -->
    <input name="newKey" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Instead, I want to totally remove the key `newKey` from body since no value passed in.

Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: Just add `else myRef.current.children[1].remove();`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks that could work. But I have 4 optional params. Just thinking if there is a better way since this means 4 times if/else blocks.

Comment: Use a loop then? (also, your approach will reload the entire react app, are you sure you don't want to switch to ajax instead? React apps are usually SPAs that submit forms in the background)

Comment: @ChrisG It's an existing piece of work which is quite tied up with other logic unfortunately. Would be interested to know how I could switch it to ajax, though guess that is another question altogether.

Comment: @ChrisG Think gonna stick will looping over the children as you suggested. You could answer if you'd like for me to accept. Thanks.